# How to add string to a query django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am writing a function which will get the value of a model depending upon the input of user.

How to join a query and string

Models.py

```
Class countries(models.Model)
    name = models.charfield(max_length=200)
    miles = models.charfield(max_length=200)
    kms = models.charfield(max_length=200)
```

.

```
From models import countries

Def abc(country):
    If country == "USA":
        A1= miles
    else:
        A1 = kms
    P1 = countries.object.get(name__exact=country). + A1
    return P1
```

Error

```
Type error : unsupported operand types for +: 'countries' and str
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QuerySet.get()` method returns an object of the `Model` subclass being queried on, which in this case is `countries`. You can't use the `+` operator on a `Model` object with a string.

You should use `getattr` to get attribute of the `countries` object instead:

```
P1 = getattr(countries.object.get(name__exact=country), A1)
```